# SQLiteConnection object for database was leaked

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks, android-contentprovider

It seems like every other time I test this app, I get the message, "A SQLiteConnection object for database [path] was leaked! Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed."

I've seen other questions here on SO that address this message, but I don't believe any of the answers fit my circumstances. For one thing, all of my database access is through a Content Provider. For another, I'm dealing with more than one database (both of which get leaked), and many cursors that hold data from one of the databases.

I would post the content provider, but my Content Provider is 1200 lines long. Let me know what parts I should pick out, and I'll edit those in. If it's relevant, there's a SQLiteOpenHelper inner class in the Content Provider. Otherwise, here's a piece from an activity that seems to be causing this problem:

```
private SimpleCursorAdapter setFixedSpinnerAdapter(String table, String[] columns){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(DBContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_OPTION + table);
        String sortOrder = (columns.length > 2 ? columns[2] : columns[1]);
        //if 3rd column specified, use it for sorting
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, sortOrder);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                cursor, new String[]{cursor.getColumnName(1)}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        return adapter;
    }// method: setFixedSpinnerAdapter(String, String[])
```

This piece of code is called by multiple Spinners to get rows of data that will populate them. And if you're wondering, no the cursor doesn't close, but I couldn't find a way to close it without losing the data in the adapter.

So let me know any ideas you have, or suggestions of parts of the Content Provider to include.

**EDIT**: Here's the logcat

```
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.162: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.170: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.170: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.170: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(7394): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+edu_dordt_grassrootsplantid+databases+plant_identification_local' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
07-15 13:24:42.170: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.178: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.186: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-15 13:24:42.186: W/CursorWrapperInner(7394): Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

The lines about the Cursor are new to this attempt, I believe, but as I said, I am not aware of any way to close the cursor when access to the cursors is only available to the method above. Also, depending on the attempt, there may also be lines saying that another database (accessed through a different part of the app, but using the same Content Provider) was also leaked.

**EDIT**:
Here's the relevant part of the query method in the Content Provider, if it helps at all.

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){
        String dbName;
        Cursor cursor;
        String tables;
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case CODE_OPTION_SEARCH://Called from setFixedSpinnerAdapter()
                dbName = DATABASE_PLANT_IDENTIFICATION_LOCAL;
                dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext(), dbName); 
                tables = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                queryBuilder.setTables(tables);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI");
        }//switch(uriMatcher.match(uri))
        cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, null, null, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }// method: ContentProvider.query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)
```

**EDIT**:
I use code formatted this way multiple times, for different spinners.

```
spnGrowthForm.setAdapter(setFixedSpinnerAdapter(
    DBContentProvider.TABLE_GROWTH_FORM_OPTION, 
    new String[]{DBContentProvider.KEY_GROWTH_FORM_ID,
    DBContentProvider.KEY_GROWTH_FORM_TEXT}));
```

The method `setFixedSpinnerAdapter(String, String[])` is the same one posted at the top. I used the `SimpleCursorAdapter` because it's the only way I've found to give me access to the ID# associated with the Spinner items.

Comment: Post the logcat showing the errors / exceptions. Simply showing a few lines out of any context as to how you're using it isn't going to help anyone help you to fix your problem.

Comment: @Squonk As I'm sure you read, I was already aware that I would need to edit in more information. I already knew the little I posted would likely not help, but I simply needed to know what else to add. Thanks for the suggestion of adding the LogCat entries.

Comment: Well first, after you get your data, how are you displaying it to the UI, that way we can figure out if your using the right type of cursor, my guess is probably not, since it's just a cursor.  At least a simplecursoradapter should be used for a database with some kind of listview.

Comment: @PeterBirdsall I added a piece of code that sets the spinner contents (by setting the adapter contents) to the contents of the Cursor.